# HSQLDB: Convert NUMERIC to HEX

Tags: hsqldb

I am using HSQLDB 2.3.3 I'm trying to convert a number into a hex. 
For example, 

input: 10 output: A

input: 100 output: 64

Is it possible to do this in hsqldb?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the standard Java static methods directly.

For example:

```
call "java.lang.Long.toHexString"(123)

SELECT "java.lang.Long.toHexString"(id) FROM Customer
```